# Clarification regarding [take] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There is a [take](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/take) tag with 82 current questions. However, not all uses of this tag are consistent.

Most of them are about the concept of obtaining the first N elements from a collection.

**Good uses IMO:**

- sparks's take()
- LINQ's take()
- Larvel's take()
- etc

However, 'take a ___' is a common idiom in english, and some questions have been tagged for this reason.

**Bad Uses IMO:**

- Take a picture
- Take a screenshot
- Take a variable (used as a synonym for get?)

Additional clarification, is a tag like this, that has so many meanings (does not differentiate by language) and so little questions useful? Or perhaps it just needs a wiki clarifying its usage?

Comment: I think the collection/lambda stuff is the preferred context for this tag. A wiki and excerpt good help to make this clear.

Comment: This tagging problem comes from people typing sentences into the "tags" box. Rather than directing your ire at the tag, consider directing it at the UI.